# Error on Google maps for EE - map doesn't display

Tags: google-maps-for-ee

I've been using Google maps for EE for plotting markers on a map through Expression Engine. It was all going ok on the dev server, until we assigned a domain name to the server. Once this happened I'm getting an error:

"This page didn't load Google Maps correctly. See the JavaScript console for technical details."

Console is giving me a MissingKeyMapError. However when I look at the same files through the server address, there's no error.

Any ideas would be appreciated!

Update: I found the answer in gmap/mod.gmap. On line 253 I added my API key to this line:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor='.$sensor.'&amp;key='.$key.'&amp;language='.$lang.'"></script>
```

So it's now:

> < script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor='.$sensor.'&key=MY-API-KEY&language='.$lang.'">

A bit messy, but at least works!